# If Else JQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I've edited a wordpress, woocommerce js file successfully. However when I try to change the standard scroll function to first check the browser width, it fails with an unexpected token ( error. I can't see where the problem is and I've tried rewriting it several ways. Code I'm trying is:

```
// Scroll to top
    $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
if( $(window).width() < 680 ) {
   scrollTop: ( $( 'form.checkout' ).offset().top - 100 )
}, 1000;
else {
   scrollTop: ( $( 'form.checkout' ).offset().top - 170 )
}, 1000;
                    }
```

Comment: Can't have an `if` like that inside the `animate`

Comment: why `}, 1000;` doesn't make sense.... try `}`

Comment: I actually have no idea what the ,1000 is for. It was in the original code so I just left it. Seems to work fine without also though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your condition check before the `animate` call - not inside it!

```
if( $(window).width() < 680 ) {
    $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
        scrollTop: ( $( 'form.checkout' ).offset().top - 100 )
    });
} else {
    $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
        scrollTop: ( $( 'form.checkout' ).offset().top - 170 )
    });
}
```

Or a different approach:

```
var offset = ($(window).width() < 680) ? 100 : 170;
$( 'html, body' ).animate( {
    scrollTop: ( $( 'form.checkout' ).offset().top - offset)
});
```

Comment: +1, In regards to your second approach I'm going to assume the OP doesn't know what a ternary conditional statement is, or the syntex which can be a bit unconventional for new comers. The syntex is the following: (condition ? do-If-True : do-If-False). Further information - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Second option worked perfectly. Thanks! And no I wasn't aware of the ternary conditional statement Brennen. Thanks for the info.